# ASP.Net MVC and jQuery Mobile page transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an app where the client has a container div on their site and they use jQuery to retrieve my app and inject it into the container.  My app is self contained as the html and javascript are all injected into client container.  Each client has it's own css file so look and feel can change as needed by client.  My app is ASP.Net MVC 4 and can be injected into a web page or a mobile app.  I'm using HTML 5, css 3.  I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 to determine if the client is mobile or web and am loading jQuery Mobile if client is mobile.

So, since the app is self contained and I'm using jquery to load subsequent pages into a div as the user interacts with the app, how do i take advantage of jQuery Mobile's page transitions?  I have to load subsequent content into a div using jQuery.  I cannot do a complete page postback.  I can't figure out how to do page transitions.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multi-page apps: your file can contain multiple pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="first">
...
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="second">
...
</div>
```

After you load additional pages and add them to DOM, then you call

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#third"));
```

More details about multi-page apps here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Comment: My ASP.Net MVC app has a single master layout file (_Layout.mobile.cshtml) where i have the <div data-role="page">...</div>.  I'm using jQuery to push all of my subsequent content pages into "<div data-role="content">@RenderBody()</div>" in the master page.  Each content page of my app is a partial view so i can use it in either the mobile master layout or the web master layout.  So, should each partial view simply be a complete page, then once i get the page to the client load it to the dom then call changePage?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a better approach.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thank you for the direction.  So, should each subsequent page reload all of the javascript files (calls to jquery, jquery mobile, etc)?  My _Layout.mobile.cshtml file is initially used and makes those calls to load jquery et all.  I'm assuming my subsequent page calls should just have the jQuery Mobile page structure, right?  If so, I should have a separate layout page for that.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you append a new page to the DOM, you don't need to reload all script files, only the page content (<div data-role="page" id="...">...</div>)

Comment: you pointed me to the multipage template and in that example page 2 already exists in the DOM.  I have the jQuery in place where I'm returning a page from MVC and can load it into the DOM then I call $.mobile.changePage($("#XXX")); to transition to the page.  I'm finding as I interact with the app that multiple versions of the same page are getting loaded into the DOM.  Since I'm adding pages dynamically, how do you make sure you are not adding duplicate pages into the DOM?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: every page has a unique id, you can check if DOM contains it already